# How to decrease the poly count in blender?

Tags: polycount

I dont have a really powerful operation system so is there any way through which I could decrease the polycount?

I have already removed doubles from my meshes and un subdivided.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can try to ctr E > unsubdivide, ot you can try a Decimate modifier, actually it depends on your topology and on your purpose, if you can share your object we can give a try...

Comment: Please edit your question and add images of your objects in edit mode so that the topology is clearly visible. Include all information on modifiers, simulations, particles and  describe what you want to do.

Comment: I am going to add a image in a few minutes

Comment: You could also try `Simplify`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Decimate modifier, setting it in “unsubdivide” mode and slightly increase the iterations (1 is normally fine).
This will drastically reduce the poly count of your mesh, but at the same time it won’t be noticeable! As the quality of the model remains almost intact (that is, if you don’t exaggerate with the iterations, of course)!

Comment: Though i would use only even numbers like 2, 4, ,6, etc... Because otherwise it will drastically change your topology into crisscrossing. Even numbers will preserve your topology while basically dividing the density.